# Redirecting local RTSP stream to React application

Tags: reactjs, node.js, rtsp

An RTSP stream is deployed on the local network that broadcasts video from a USB camera. Everything works through VLC Media player. How can I get the RTSP stream on nest.js backend and redirect it to `React`  frontend (Getting it from the backend is necessary because not only the frontend will use the stream).

I tried this on the server

```
const NodeMediaServer = require('node-media-server');

const config = {
    rtmp: {
      port: 1488,
      chunk_size: 60000,
      gop_cache: false,
      ping: 60,
      ping_timeout: 30,
    },
    http: {
      port: 6666,
      allow_origin: '*',
    },
    relay: {
      ffmpeg: './ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl/bin/ffmpeg.exe', 
      tasks: [
        {
          app: 'live',
          mode: 'static',
          edge: `rtsp://192.168.1.238:8554/mystream`,
        },
      ],
    },
  };
  


const nms = new NodeMediaServer(config);
nms.run();

nms.on('prePublish', (id, streamPath, args) => {
  if (streamPath.indexOf('mystream') === -1) {
    nms.getSession(id).reject();
  }
});

console.log('Node Media Server is running');
```

And this on the `React`

```
import { Player, ControlBar } from 'video-react';
function App() {

    return (
        <div>
            <Player
                playsInline
                autoPlay
                src="http://localhost:8001/live/mystream.m3u8"
            >
                <ControlBar autoHide={false}/>
            </Player>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```